# Plotting both NDVI & EVI (or multiple) charts on the panel derived from MODIS as user defines geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to plot charts of NDVI and EVI from MODIS image collection together as the user defines the region of interest (Geometry). It seems like I cannot plot both together using .setSeriesNames function. I am able to plot only one chart at a time in Google Earth Engine (see my comment "// if I set this off, it plots one chart").

Can someone help me plot both (or multiple) charts on the panel?

Here is the script:

```
//*************************************************
//************************************************* 
// Source: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/drawing-tools-region-reduction
// Get the drawing tools widget object; define it as a variable 
// for convenience in recalling it later.
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();

// Hide the default drawing tools
drawingTools.setShown(false);

// Setup a while loop to clear all existing geometries
while (drawingTools.layers().length() > 0) {
  var layer = drawingTools.layers().get(0);
  drawingTools.layers().remove(layer);
}

// Initialize a dummy GeometryLayer with null geometry 
// to act as a placeholder for drawn geometries.
var dummyGeometry =
    ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'geometry', color: '0000ff'});

drawingTools.layers().add(dummyGeometry);

// Define the geometry clearing function.
function clearGeometry() {
  var layers = drawingTools.layers();
  layers.get(0).geometries().remove(layers.get(0).geometries().get(0));
}

// Define functions that will be called when 
// each respective drawing button is clicked.

function drawRectangle() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('rectangle');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

function drawPolygon() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('polygon');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

function drawPoint() {
  clearGeometry();
  drawingTools.setShape('point');
  drawingTools.draw();
}

// Define a panel to hold the time series chart.
var chartPanel = ui.Panel({
  style:
      {height: '235px', width: '600px', position: 'bottom-center', shown: false}
});

// Add the panel to the Map.
Map.add(chartPanel);

// Define a function that gets called on geometry drawing completion and 
// editing events to generate a time series chart for the drawn region.
function chartNdviTimeSeries() {
  // Make the chart panel visible the first time a geometry is drawn.
  if (!chartPanel.style().get('shown')) {
    chartPanel.style().set('shown', true);
  }

  // Get the drawn geometry; it will define the reduction region.
  var aoi = drawingTools.layers().get(0).getEeObject();

  // Set the drawing mode back to null; turns drawing off.
  drawingTools.setShape(null);

  // Reduction scale is based on map scale to avoid memory/timeout errors.
  var mapScale = Map.getScale();
  var scale = mapScale > 5000 ? mapScale * 2 : 5000;

// Image collection.
var Modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
            .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);
print (Modis)

// Set chart style properties.
var chartStyle = {
  title: 'MODIS Average Value by Date',
  titlePostion: 'top-center',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  hAxis: {title: 'date', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Normalized Indices'}, //  vAxis: {title: 'NDSI', maxValue: 1, minValue: -1},
  series: {
      0: {lineWidth: 2, color: 'E37D05'},
      1: {lineWidth: 2, color: '1D6B99', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]}
      }
}

// Chart NDVI time series for the selected area of interest.
var chart = ui.Chart.image
              .seriesByRegion({
              imageCollection: Modis, // use this for entire timelapse
              regions: aoi,
              reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
              //band: ['NDVI', 'EVI'], 
                    //band: ['EVI'],
              scale: scale,
              xProperty: 'system:time_start'
              })
              .setSeriesNames(['NDVI', 'EVI'])// if I set this off, it plots one chart
              .setOptions(chartStyle);

  // Replace the existing chart in the chart panel with the new chart.
  chartPanel.widgets().reset([chart]);
}

// Set the drawing tools widget to listen for geometry drawing and 
// editing events and respond with the chartNdviTimeSeries function.
drawingTools.onDraw(ui.util.debounce(chartNdviTimeSeries, 500));
drawingTools.onEdit(ui.util.debounce(chartNdviTimeSeries, 500));

// User interface
var symbol = {
  rectangle: '⬛',
  polygon: '',
  point: '',
};

// Define a ui.Panel to hold app instructions and 
// the geometry drawing buttons. 
var controlPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label('1. Select a drawing mode.'),
    ui.Button({
      label: symbol.rectangle + ' Rectangle',
      onClick: drawRectangle,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
    }),
    ui.Button({
      label: symbol.polygon + ' Polygon',
      onClick: drawPolygon,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
    }),
    ui.Button({
      label: symbol.point + ' Point',
      onClick: drawPoint,
      style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
    }),
    ui.Label('2. Draw a geometry.'),
    ui.Label('3. Wait for chart to render.'),
    ui.Label(
        '4. Repeat 1-3 or edit/move\ngeometry for a new chart.',
        {whiteSpace: 'pre'})
  ],
  style: {position: 'top-left'},
  layout: null,
});

// Add the panel to the Map.
Map.add(controlPanel);

//*************************************************
//*************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like multiple bands shown in the same chart, you should use [`ui.Chart.image.series`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection#uichartimageseries) instead of [`ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection#uichartimageseriesbyregion). I've modified the following sections of your code to show the legend (so you can know what line is what band) and implemented `ui.Chart.image.series`.

```js
// Set chart style properties.
var chartStyle = {
  title: 'MODIS Average Value by Date',
  titlePostion: 'top-center',
  hAxis: {title: 'date', format: 'MM-yy', gridlines: {count: 12}},
  vAxis: {title: 'Normalized Indices'}, //  vAxis: {title: 'NDSI', maxValue: 1, minValue: -1},
  series: {
      0: {lineWidth: 2, color: 'E37D05'},
      1: {lineWidth: 2, color: '1D6B99', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]}
      }
}

// Chart NDVI time series for the selected area of interest.
var chart = ui.Chart.image
              .series({
              imageCollection: Modis, // use this for entire timelapse
              region: aoi,
              reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
              scale: scale,
              xProperty: 'system:time_start'
              })
              .setOptions(chartStyle);
```

[Full Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b45b2399734369a6508b21f36681bf81)

[image]